# Creating a single elastic/liquid layout screen for Android

Tags: android, resize, liquid-layout, elasticlayout

Is it possible create a `liquid/elastic` screen layout on `Android` that resizes to fit all screen sizes?

Currently I'm playing around with different layouts for small, medium, large, xlarge etc, but all I really need is a single layout that just scales to fit.

**Eg. a percentage based layout.**

The app I'm creating doesn't specifically need to take advantage of larger screens in terms of making more use of the space.

The home screen is just 2 images, a bunch of buttons, and an advert at the bottom, and I simply wish for the advert to remain at the bottom, whilst everything else scales up accordingly depending on screen size.

It seems very over-complicated to have to product 4 different layouts for a very simplistic interface.

Advice much appreciated!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. I don't think its possible

Comment: Kindly add layout screenshot so i can help you with the layout.

Comment: Here's a mockup of the layout we want to use http://www.pixelkicks.co.uk/_download/Sample-Android-Layout.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

or

Layout with Weights like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ADV" />

</LinearLayout>
```